# Trying to use variables from selenium to make an email (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, email, selenium-webdriver

This is my first post and i'm quite new at python, let alone emailing from it. So my goal is to scrape the first 5 articles from a website and send an email it to myself. For now i just need it so that when I run it it sends it once from one email address to another. I'll worry about scheduling it later once i'm over this problem.  So this is my code that just scrapes the articles using selenium.
Edit: I just ran the this first block of code and found it prints the same story 5 times. If someone could also fix that so it prints 5 different news stories, that would be great.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


def getnews():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get("https://community.elitedangerous.com/en/")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    news = driver.find_element_by_class_name("article")
    divider =("_____________________________________________________________________________________________________")
    for i in range(0,6):
        print(news.text)
        print(divider)
    driver.quit()


getnews()
```

if you run that you will get my nerdy news. I have an email code that i found of the internet that is here. This works well for basic text.

```
import smtplib


with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.login('mysendingemail.gmail.com', 'myverysecurepassword')

    subject = "this is the title"
    body = "this is the body of the email"

    #i dont really get what this means 
    msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'

    smtp.sendmail('mysendingemail.gmailcom', 'myotheremail@gmail.com',msg)
```

I think my question is whether i am able to email myself these values and then maybe later make it so it would email me weekly. I have no idea how i would even begin to know how to do that but my main question now is how to get the text from the website on an email. Thanks in advance.

after some comments about making a list, I did this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import smtplib



def get_news():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get("https://community.elitedangerous.com/en/")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    v=2

    divider =("_____________________________________________________________________________________________________")
    list = []
    for x in range(0, 5):
        if v <= 7:
            xpath = (str('//*[@id="block-system-main"]/div[' + str(v) + ']'))
            news = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
            body = news.text
            # print(body)
            # print(divider)
            list.append(news.text)

            v += 1
        else:
            break

    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.login('senderemail@email.com', 'password for email')

        subject = "news"
        body = str(list)

        msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'

        smtp.sendmail('sender email.com', 'recieveremail.com', msg)


get_news()
```

When i run this i get a UnicodeEncodeError. Is this because the list isnt going into a string properly?

Comment: _I have no idea how i would even begin to know how to do that but my main question now is how to get the text from the website on an email._ That's quite broad/vague, and likely off-topic. Please see [help/on-topic], [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The `subject` variable is the title of the email, and the `body` variable is what's in the email. Here's a simple diagram:

[image: email diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Why not compile the lines of text from the news articles into an array of strings (maybe each entry being an article), and have your getnews() function return that array, which could then be invoked in the script for sending emails. Let me know if this makes sense!

Also, just a tip but not essential, in Python it's customary to use snake-case for functions and variables, so getnews() would be better written as get_news(). Again this is a nitpick but it's always good to follow the language's conventions.

Comment: Thanks ill try that. Thank you for the nitpick as well. I appreciate any sort of way to make my code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

This should print the first 5 elements.

```
news = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("article")
for new in news[:5]:
    print(new.text)
    print(divider)
```

I'd suggest appending it to a list.

```
lst=[]
news = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("article")
for new in news[:5]:
    lst.append(new.text)
```

So you can just send your list to the message.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. I was unaware or had forgotten about the .append() so that made my life a lot easier. I put my new code as the last code block but i get an error when i run it. (UnicodeEncodeError)

Comment: Try with my top method to see the first 5 articles. You can just use find_elements.

Comment: Ok so i put that in instead of my first for loop. It works well but i still get the same error.

Comment: So now you have to convert a list into a string.

Comment: I know i am incredibly incompetent but im just wondering would that mean in the email portion i say `body = str(lst)` because that didnt work. Im so sorry to keep bothering you.